# File created in interactive session within container dissapears after exiting container (container running in background)

Tags: docker, containers

---

**Objective**

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is to install a bunch of software but store the commands run in the Dockerfile in the end. I was planning on recording the installation process by running the "script" function to record the commands run on the command line. I would like to know why it doesn't work but if there is a better way of doing it, I am all ears!

---

**The issue**

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I can't seem to figure it out. When I create a dummy file within my docker container it dissapears when I exit the container even though the container is running in the background.

---

**Attempt**

This is my Dockerfile

```
##Filename = Dockerfile
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /dummy_folder

CMD ["echo", "hello world"]
```

I build the image and run it in the background.

```
docker build -t my_test_image:v1.0 .
docker run -d e9e949b5d85a tail -f /dev/null
```

Now I can see my container running in the background

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6f4da7a1b74d        e9e949b5d85a        "tail -f /dev/null"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes                           trusting_poincare
```

If I create an interactive session and just dump a file in /dummy_folder and exit. When I create a new interactive session /dummy_folder is empty again.

```
docker run -it e9e949b5d85a /bin/bash
echo "dummy" > dummy
exit
docker run -it e9e949b5d85a /bin/bash
ls -alh /dummy_folder
```

P.S tail -f /dev/null is just a trick I use to keep the container running in the background as just running it with the flag -d doesn't work for centos containers apparently.

I am running Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

Thanks
Sabri

Comment: Each time you run the container, it starts from the same state you built it. What you changed in one `run` command won't persist the next time it's run.

Comment: So there is no way to mimic what you pretty much can accomplish with docker-compose where you can create a volume that links a folder on local with the container?

Comment: Yes, [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) review how you can do that. Is your objective just to mount a local folder to a directory container?

Comment: I'd suggest iterating on this by opening the Dockerfile in your choice of editor and repeating `docker build`.  Then you'll have it written down what you've done already, instead of needing to reverse-engineer what you're doing.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yeah of course but the reason I would like to avoid that in this case is because I will have to install multiple software and dependencies for this container and it would be easier to do that interactively instead of rebuillding the image over and over again fixing the errors as I go along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new container every time your run `docker run ...` . What I think you're trying to do is run a shell on the same container you started with `docker run -d e9e949b5d85a tail -f /dev/null`. If so, the Docker command your'e looking for is `exec`

Start an interactive session using the container ID (not the image ID) and do your stuff

```
docker exec -it 6f4da7a1b74d /bin/bash
$ echo "dummy" > dummy
$ exit
```

And then check the contents again with `exec`

```
docker exec 6f4da7a1b74d ls -alh /dummy_folder
```

Comment: answers my question exactly and I clearly should have read the usage more clearly as it accurately states that "docker run" will run a new container while "docker exec" will run an already exisiting container. 

Thanks
Sabri